How to create sub question with gtsummary in R (modalities reorganisation, pivot ...)
Hi and thanks for your help !
This is what my data looks like :



q21a
q21b
q21c
weight
year




Yes
No
Yes
1
2003


No
Yes
Yes
0.23
2022



It is extracted from a survey.
q21a = "Would you recommand to a friend to go skydiving ?"
q21b = "Would you recommand to family to go skydiving ?"
q21c = "Would you recommand to your partner to go skydiving ?"
As the structure of the question is always the same, and that we are only interested in the Yes (as the complementary is always no),
I would like my gtsummary modalities on the left to look like that :
Would you recommand to ... to go skydiving ? = Yes
    Family
    Friend
    Partner

Thank you so much for your help ! It's been a headache
For now this is my code :
weighted_skydive <- svydesign(id = ~1, weights = ~weight, data = df)

# Create the summary table
summary_skydive <- weighted_skydive %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = year, 
    include = -c("weight"),
    label = list(
      q21a ~  "Would you recommand to a friend to go skydiving ?",
      q21b ~ "Would you recommand to family to go skydiving ?",
      q21c ~ "Would you recommand to your partner to go skydiving ?"
    ),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    missing = "no" 
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>% 
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Year**")


I think this helper will get you what you're after. https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/add_variable_grouping.html
